# UI Design of News Magazine with borders, boxes or no seperation

Tags: website-design, navigation, layout

Im building a news website and want to know which UI Design is the best in terms of readability, findabiltiy and focusing of each / important sections?

### **Example 1** - Boxed Layout - each section has its own area:

[image]

---

### **Example 2** - No Borders - no boxes

[image]

---

### **Example 3** - Small Font, small margin with dividing lines:

[image]

---

### **Example 4** - Like a Blog - big post sections & big font - no borders

[image]

[image]

### Your Examples? A combination of example...?

Comment: There is no 'best' here. It all comes down to your particular implementation of these and how it fits with your particular content and reader's needs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Graphic/UI Design and hence should be migrated to http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The more you can lose design elements that doesn't provide value to the reader, the better. Vertical and horizontal lines, fat headers with disturbing colours or boxes without meaning.

If you can work with negative space (a.k.a [White Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_space_(visual_arts))) for clarity you make your news site easy on the eye and less stressful to brows through where content stand out instead of design elements.

But that kind of site may look dull and you need to add colors on the site to make it look more appealing. The best balance between readability and design is where you should aim.

In your list of examples, The No 2 is close to what I refer to.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what kind of a news site you are developing and without understanding what kind of an audience you want to draw/keep and making assumptions for the same, I would cautiously suggest a combination:
- With Example 2, you are able to let the content be the star by taking away any visually distracting elements of the page. 
- With Example 3, you allow the user to discover content by searching (search box) or by navigating based on the most popular content (Top Hits, Most Popular)

Your best bet is to first understand the demographics and who your users are so you can better manage the findability and readability of the content and highlight the appropriate content based on your findings.